# Using Terraform 0.10.8 from behind a proxy

Tags: terraform

I asked over at stack overflow and I am not getting any eyes.

I am trying to get terraform init to run on an ubuntu host behind a proxy.
I have exported the two variables http_proxy and https_proxy. Testing with curl and wget works fine, so I know I can get to the internet.

Any idea why terraform does not seem to be using the proxy?

This is the error I am getting

```
Error installing provider "aws": 
Get https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/: Forbidden.
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform does not need a HTTP Proxy, it only uses https.

`HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.my.corp:8443 terraform … command` should work. Terraform is actually cases sensitive in regards to ENV vars, so try upper- and lowercase Version of `HTTPS_PROXY`.